# Let $F(x) \in GF(p)[x]$ a prime polynomial deg $n>0$, if $gcd(F,x^{q^i}-x)=1$ for $i=1,2,...,[n/2]$ $\iff$ $F$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I want to prove this claim below as an exercise for exam:

> Let $F(x) \in GF(p)[x]$ a prime polynomial deg $n>0$, if
>   $gcd(F,x^{q^i}-x)=1$ for $i=1,2,...,[n/2]$ $\iff$ $F$ is irreducible

Here a trace of my proof:

Suppose $F$ reducible.

Then $F(x)=G(x)H(x)$ product of at least two irreducible polynomial, and since $deg F=n \Rightarrow degf \geq degG \times degH$. Suppose then $degG=degH=[n/2]$.

We know that for $q=p^k \Rightarrow x^{q^i}-x=$ {product of all irreducible polynomial of $GF(q)$}. But from the product of thos polynomial, must emerge a polynomial with degree at least $[n/2]$, so  $gcd(F,x^{q^i}-x) \not =1$. 
So in order to have $gcd(F,x^{q^i}-x)  =1$, $F$ must be irreducible.

I have difficulties in translating my ideas in mathematical format so thanks for any kind of hints or corrections, thanks.

Comment: Contains some gaps.

Comment: Over a field, what's the difference between a *prime* and an *irreducible* polynomial?

Comment: Over a field, prime polynomial and irreducible polynomial are the same,  polynomials that cannot be factored into polynomials of lower degree

Comment: @Wuestenfux how can I complete my proof? Can you give some hints of those gaps?

Comment: You can assume that one of the polynomials $G, H$ has degree $\leq n/2$.

Comment: $X^{q^m}-X$ is the product of irred. polynomials of degree $d$ where $d$ divides $m$.